# How to get a small letter version of \mathcal{O}

Tags: symbols

I am trying to produce a small letter version of `\mathcal{O}` which looks the same, just smaller - like "O" and "o". However `\mathcal{o}` produces a very different symbol.
Has anyone an idea how to manage this?

Comment: only uppercase letters are implemented for the default `\mathcal`.  another font will be required.  there aren't any listed in the "comprehensive symbols list" (`texdoc comprehensive`, but i think there's a lowercase alphabet in the `stix` and `xits` fonts.  search for those names in this forum; unfortunately, i haven't time to do that research now.

Comment: oh, [welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\smallO{
  \mathchoice
    {{\scriptstyle\mathcal{O}}}% \displaystyle
    {{\scriptstyle\mathcal{O}}}% \textstyle
    {{\scriptscriptstyle\mathcal{O}}}% \scriptstyle
    {\scalebox{.7}{$\scriptscriptstyle\mathcal{O}$}}%\scriptscriptstyle
  }

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{O} \smallO$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot; I changed the factor in \scalebox from 0.7 to 0.6, so it has the perfect "smallness"^^

Answer (score 5):

`\mathcal{}` uses only **CAPITAL LETTER ALPHABETS**. To use **small letter alphabets**, you can use `\mathscr{}`, which also supports **CAPITAL LETTER ALPHABETS**. To use `\mathscr{}`, you need to include the package `unicode-math`and use the font `XITS Math` and compile the document using `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{O}$ with \verb+\mathcal{}+ \par
$\mathscr{o}$ with \verb+\mathscr{}+ \par
$\mathscr{O}$ with \verb+\mathscr{}+
\end{document}
```

[image]