# How to get a small letter version of \mathcal{O} inside table caption

Tags: fonts, captions

I have used the suggestion given in  [How to get a small letter version of \mathcal{O}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191059/how-to-get-a-small-letter-version-of-mathcalo), and it worked perfectly, except when `\smallO` is inside a table caption. How to overcome the nuisance?

Comment: `\protect\smallO` with `\smallO` defined as in the linked question

Comment: Being a math letter, did you employ it as `$\smallO$` (with the dollar signs)?

Answer (score 4):

the `\mathchoice` construct used in the linked answer would not work in a moving argument such as `\caption` so you would need

```
\caption{...$\protect\smallO{n}$....}
```

or use `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand` to define `\smallO`.